# A matrix with duplicate rows over commutative ring always has zero determinant, is that true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, determinant

Let $R=(R,+,\cdot)$ be a commutative ring and $A$ is a square matrix over $R.$ It is well known that if two rows (or columns) of $A$ are swapped, then its determinant is changed by sign. As a consequence, if $A$ has the same two rows, then swapping such same rows doesn't change the matrix but changes its sign of the determinant. Thus $|A|=-|A|,$ that is $|A|$ has its own inverse in the additive group $(R,+).$ I can not conclude that $|A|=0$ since there are rings with the property that $r=-r$ does not implies $r=0,$ for instance take $r=3$ in the ring $\Bbb Z_6.$ My question: is always true $|A|=0$ when it has duplicate rows? If so, how to prove it?\

Note, $|A|$ is defined as

$$|A| := \sum_{\pi\in S_n} \mbox{sign}(\pi)\ a_{1\pi(1)}\cdots a_{n\pi(n)}$$

where $S_n$ is the group of permutations on $\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: What is the definition of determinant that you are working with?

Comment: I just edited what we mean by |A|. Thank for asking.

Comment: If you are allowed to use row operations, subtract one of the equal rows from the other. That gives a row of zeroes, and you can show that has determinant zero using cofactor or from the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Suppose, say, that the first two columns are equal. Let $\sigma\in S_n$ and let $\iota$ be the element of $S_n$ such that

- $\iota(1)=2$;
- $\iota(2)=1$;
- $\iota(j)=j$ if $j>2$.

Then $\operatorname{sgn}(\iota)=-1$, and therefore $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma\iota)=-\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)$. So$$\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)a_{1\sigma(1)}a_{2\sigma(2)}\ldots a_{n\sigma(n)}+\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma\iota)a_{1(\sigma\iota)(1)}a_{2(\sigma\iota)(2)}\ldots a_{n(\sigma\iota)(n)}=0.$$It follows from this that $\det A=0$.

Comment: Did you mean as $\sigma$ runs in the entire $S_n$, so are $\sigma\iota$, hence your displayed equation above becomes $|A|+|A|=0.$ But how can $|A|=0$?

Comment: Split the sum into two sums: a sum where you run over permutations in $A_n$, and a sum where you run over permutations of the form $\sigma\iota$ where $\sigma\in A_n$. As you can easily conclude from the answer, the second sum is the negative of the first one.

Comment: If $\sigma\in A_n$, that is, if $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)=1$, then $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma\iota)=-1$. So, as $\sigma$ runs in $A_n$, $\sigma\iota$ runs in $\{\sigma\in S_n\mid\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)=-1\}$. And, for each pair consisting of $\sigma$ and $\sigma\iota$, the contributions of $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)a_{1\sigma(1)}a_{2\sigma(2)}\ldots a_{n\sigma(n)}$ and of $\operatorname{sgn}(\iota\sigma)a_{1(\sigma\iota)(1)}a_{2(\sigma\iota)(2)}\ldots a_{n(\iota\sigma)(n)}$ to the determinant of $A$ cancel each other.

Comment: I think the displayed equation is not true, take $\sigma=(123)\in A_3$ so that $\sigma(12)=(13)$. Then the left hand side is $+a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}-a_{13}a_{22}a_{31}$ may not equal to zero.

Comment: @erdos Yes, it's zero as $a_{12} = a_{22}$ and $a_{23} = a_{13}$ by the assumption on the rows.

Comment: @erdos Consider it like this: let $P_n = \{\sigma\in S_n : \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)=1\}$, $N_n = \{\sigma\in S_n : \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)=-1\}$, and $T(\sigma) = \iota\sigma$. Then $T$ maps $P_n$ bijectively to $N_n$, so$$\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}f(\sigma) = \sum_{\sigma\in P_n}f(\sigma) + \sum_{\sigma\in N_n}f(\sigma) = \sum_{\sigma\in P_n}f(\sigma) + \sum_{\sigma\in P_n}f(\sigma\iota) = 0.$$

Comment: Yes, I see it. Very elegant solution, direct from the definition without use of previous known theorems. Thank you Sir..

Comment: I'm glad I could help.